# Smallest Integer Greater than Very Large Number

Tags: math, matlab, numbers, integer

I am trying to find the smallest integer greater than a very large number (for example, exp(5000000)). How would I go about doing this? If not programmatically (because this evaluates to infinity or overflow in MATLAB or my calculator), then mathematically? (Already tried exp(floor(log(exp(5000*1024)))) but that will just give infinity).

Comment: what exactly do you mean by finding it mathematically? are you looking for a function that gives its nth digit, for example?

Comment: just to give you an idea how big this number is, I tried the following in MATLAB with the Symbolic Toolbox: `ceil( sym('exp(5000000)') )` the result is enormous: http://pastebin.com/BXDbPydL

Comment: Yes. It has roughly 2.17 million digits. Enormous.

Comment: I don't see why the size of the number should be an issue. Even if one use a whole byte to write a single digit, the file containing this number still wouldn't be bigger than 3Mb.

Answer (score 3):

You want something to provide variable-precision arithmetic, such as the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/products/symbolic/index.html), and the [ceiling function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ceil.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compute all the digits of a large number, the easiest solution is probably to use Maple or Mathematica. If you just want something simple and free, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

For example:

- [ceil(exp(500)) in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ceiling%5BExp%5B500%5D%5D)
- [ceil(exp(500000)) in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ceiling%5BExp%5B5000000%5D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library that handles big numbers.

My google karma seems to point to [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/products/symbolic/index.html),

Comment: But N is the integer, not the number. exp(5000000) may not necessarily be an integer.

Comment: @JustinM You are right. I have removed the incorrect statement.

Answer (score -2):

Like Klas sais. If you integer i **N** then the smallest larger integer is **N+1**. To calculate this using for example C you could write a function like

```
unsigned long smallestLargerInteger(unsigned long startNum) {
  return startNum +1;
}
```

To make sure you don't overflow the **long** you could have something like

```
#define __HALF_MAX_SIGNED(type) ((type)1 << (sizeof(type)*8-2))
#define __MAX_SIGNED(type) (__HALF_MAX_SIGNED(type) - 1 + __HALF_MAX_SIGNED(type))
#define __MIN_SIGNED(type) (-1 - __MAX_SIGNED(type))

#define __MIN(type) ((type)-1 < 1?__MIN_SIGNED(type):(type)0)
#define __MAX(type) ((type)~__MIN(type))

unsigned long smallestLargerInteger(unsigned long startNum) {
  if(__MAX(long) == startNum) {
    // handle overflow error messaging here
  }

  return startNum +1;
}
```